# how to display datagridview row into textbox and picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a problem right now. I successfully retrieved the data into `textbox` and `picturebox`. But, when I click different row the data always display the first row in the `datagridview`. Of course, I want to display the data from other rows.

Here is the sample code I use.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = StaffInfo();
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

        textBox1.Text = row["FName"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = row["MName"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = row["LName"].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = row["Username"].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = row["Password"].ToString();
        textBox6.Text = row["Password"].ToString();
        pictureBox3.Image = LoadPhoto((byte[])row["AccImage"]);
    }

    private Image LoadPhoto(byte[] photo)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo);
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

    private DataTable StaffInfo()
    {
        DataTable dtStaff = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\patrick\Desktop\New folder\Database1.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts1";

        using (conn)
        {
            using (cmd)
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", textBox1.Text);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dtStaff.Load(reader);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        return dtStaff;
    }
```

Also, I'm using `Microsoft Access Database`

Comment: Use the DataSource and selection row index of your grid.  You are using something else and always using row zero.  Your query doesn't have an FName parameter.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and i'll update it.

Comment: `DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];` is your issue. Doing `var row = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];` would work, though, you shouldn't have to query every time a cell is clicked. Like LarsTech said, use the DataGridView's DataSource.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for you help guys, I appreciate it.